# After setting minsdkversion to 24, i got this error

Tags: flutter

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\payzfast_live>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO LB6 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'`.

  > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/payzfast_live/and
  >   roid/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 69; Attribute "name
  >   " bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified
  >   for element "application".
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option t
  o get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
>  Running Gradle task
>   'assembleDebug'...
>  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done
>   86.7s
>  Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: can you post the code in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dart packages in pubspec.yaml that could be the issue. I am using minSdkVersion 21 and have not been able to use a higher version with the plugins that my project depends on